# How to access individual documents in textmatrix in R

Tags: r, lsa

I have a textmatrix in R that looks like the following:

[image: textmatrix]

I am trying to create one textmatrix from training and testing data.  How can I access the different document columns to put into another textmatrix?

Comment: Not sure but try something like `testingSpace$matrix[,"D4"]` or `testingSpace$matrix[,4:6]` (not tested)

Comment: $matrix doesn't exist for some reason, and when I do testingSpace[,"D4"], it says "subscript out of bounds"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found to do it so far is to access it by subscript, i.e. testingSpace[,i]

Still not sure why testingSpace$matrix doesn't seem to exist, so if anyone knows, please let me know.